# python 2.7 select words in list prior to number

Tags: python, list, select

I have a text file, a.txt, with:

```
Hydrocortisone 10 MG/ML Topical Cream
Tretinoin 0.25 MG/ML Topical Cream
Benzoyl Peroxide 50 MG/ML Topical Lotion
Ketoconazole 20 MG/ML Medicated Shampoo
etc
```

I need a way to select any words prior to the first number, and write these to another file, b.txt:

```
Hydrocortisone
Tretinoin 
Benzoyl Peroxide
Ketoconazole
etc
```

I've a basic idea of how to do find and replace in files, but such a limited grasp of python that it is almost laughable, so my initial idea was to do something like

```
infile = open('a.txt')
outfile = open('b.txt', 'w')
replacements = {'1':'', '2':'' up to twenty and then a list based on words commonly occuring after the numbers such as 'topical':'' etc}
for line in infile:
for src, target in replacements.iteritems():
line = line.replace(src, target)
outfile.write(line)
infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

but all that will do is delete stuff specified in 'replacements'.  There are thousands of variations so I couldn't list them all.

Sorry for not being clearer and thanks for any help

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Sorry but this is not how StackOverflow works. You must show effort in researching, posting the code you have tried, explaining why it's not working, and asking an specific question.

Comment: regex can do this, but it may be a tad advanced for this specific case

Comment: regex man regex http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, which will split on the number, and get you the name parts:

```
import re

exp = re.compile(r'(\d+\.?\d+)')

with open('mainfile.txt') as f, open('names.txt','w') as out:
   for line in f:
      line = line.strip()
      if len(line):
           try:
               out.write('{}\n'.format(re.split(exp, line)[0].strip()))
           except:
               print('Could not parse {}'.format(line))
```

The regular expression `\d+\.?\d+` means:

- `\d+` one or more digits
- `\.?` an optional `.` (note in regular expressions `.` has special meaning, so we escape it when we mean the *literal* `.`)
- `\d+` followed by one or more digits

The `()` around it makes it to a capture group; which results in the following:

```
>>> x = r'(\d+\.?\d+)'
>>> l = 'Benzoyl Peroxide 50 MG/ML Topical Lotion'
>>> re.split(x, l)
['Benzoyl Peroxide ', '50', ' MG/ML Topical Lotion']
```

Comment: Brilliant, that works perfectly.  Thank you ever so much and thank you for explaining it, it really helps me learn.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do a loop and use `isdigit()` to determine the first number? Something like:

```
writef = open('b.txt', 'w')
with open('a.txt') as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        words = line.split()
        for i in range(len(words)):
            if words[i].replace('.', '').isdigit():
                writef.write(words[i-1] + '\n')
                continue
writef.close()
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I must be doing something dense as I get SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop.  sorry and thanks for your help

Comment: @lobe Oh that's my fault though, forgot to add `while` :)